# Is it possible to execute indented lines from another file in Python?

Tags: python, include, indentation

Say, I have two files `demo.py`

```
# demo.py
from pathlib import Path
for i in range(5):
    exec(Path('another_file.txt').read_text())
```

and `another_file.txt` (note the indent)

```
    print(i)
```

Is it possible to make `python demo.py` run?

N.B. This is useful when using Page (or wxformbuilder or pyqt's designer) to generate a GUI layout where skeletons of callback functioins are automatically generated. The skeletons will have to be modified, at the same time, each iteration overwrites the skeletons -- code snippets will have to be copied back. Anyway, you know what I am talking about if you have used any of Page or wxformbuilder or pyqt's designer.

Comment: Why are you calling `exec` on the contents of files? Almost always a bad idea

Comment: I just want to make it work and worry about security and other issues later. Thanks.

Comment: Calling `python demo.py` will run the file. If you are using [windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) you may have to add `if __name__ == '__main__':` to get the contents to run

Comment: Well, if you tried you'd know `python demo.py` would result in errors (IndentationError: unexpected indent).

Comment: Does the error occur when `exec`ing the file?

Comment: No, I wouldn't know because I don't write programs that call `exec` on the contents of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the basic problem by removing the indent:

```
from pathlib import Path
import textwrap
for i in range(5):
    exec(textwrap.dedent(Path('another_file.txt').read_text()))
```

There are still two rather major problems with this:

There are serious security implications here.  You're running code without including it in your project.  The idea that you can "worry about security and other issues later" will cause you pain at a later point.  You'll see similar advice on this site with avoiding SQL injection.  That later date may never come, and even if it does, there's a very real chance you won't remember or correctly identify all of the problems.  It's absolutely better to avoid the problems in the first place.

Also, with dynamic code like this, you run the very real risk of running into a syntax error with a call stack that shows you nothing about where the code is from.  It's not bad for simple cases like this, but as you add more and more complexity to a project like this, you'll likely find you're adding more support to help you debug issues you run into, rather than spending your time adding features.

And, combining these two problems can be fun.  It's contrived, but if you changed the `for` loop to a `while` loop like this:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    exec(textwrap.dedent(Path('another_file.txt').read_text()))
    i += 1
```

And then modified the text file to be this:

```
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

It's trivial to understand why it's no longer operating the 5 times you expect, but as both "sides" of this project get more complex, figuring out the complex interplay between the elements will get much harder.

In short, don't use `eval`.  Future you will thank past you for making your life easier.